# What is the best way to represent restaurant menu in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

trying to build proper architecture for local app, to show menu of few restaurants
So I would have few places in DB, they all can have different menu categories and all different items in there, what would you recommend as the best way to represent this in mongodb (Im using mongoose with node.js)

Comment: This is way too broad a question for Stack Overflow.  Just start with your best guess, find problems with it as you use it, come up with better ideas, and repeat.

Comment: Im totally lost how to implement the better querying mechanism, since querying embedded documents doesnt sound very good, or editing, especially if the nesting level is like 3rd

Comment: If you haven't read it already, start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Comment: Thanks a lot, still was looking for an advice from those who maybe already built similar structure

Comment: If you are concerned about the document-based approach being inefficient, why wouldn't you choose your tool based on your preferred data organization, rather than the other way around? Having said that, if you are talking about a "few" restaurants and their menus, I really don't think you need to worry much about performance. Also, in your question you give no indication of the types of queries you would want to perform against the data, which would really be the main driver of how to organize them. Is the typical query "get me the menu for Chez Tony" or is it "show me places with spaghetti"?

Comment: That is a very good comment, thanks, made me rethink my designing process, will update question in the evening

Answer (score 2):

Check [Data Model Design](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) on mongoDB manual.

In your case, you can do something like this:

restaurant document:

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId1>,
  restaurantname: "123xyz",
  phone: "123456"
  adress: "Adress"
}
```

categories document:

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId2>,
  restaurant_id: <ObjectId1>,
  cat_name: "breakfast"
}
```

subcat document:

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId3>,
  categories_id: <ObjectId2>,
  subcat_name: "Eggs"
}
```

saucer document:

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId4>,
  subcat_id: <ObjectId3>,
  saucer_name: "fried eggs",
  description: "fried eggs description",
  price: "$00.00"
}
```

And check [Data modeling embedding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#data-modeling-embedding) in this case:

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId1>,
  restaurantname: "123xyz",
  phone: "123456"
  adress: "Adress"
  categories:
    {
      _id: <ObjectId2>,
      cat_name: "breakfast",
      subcat:
        {
          _id: <ObjectId3>,
          subcat_name: "Eggs"
          saucer document
            {
              _id: <ObjectId4>,
              saucer_name: "fried eggs",
              description: "fried eggs description",
              price: "$00.00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```